# How to show all archived messages in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-archive

How do we search for all our archived messages in Gmail?

Non-archived messages should not be displayed,

Only the archived messages should be shown.

Comment: How do you define simplest? I don't think there's a one-click command for that.

Comment: Padding out your question with words complaining about the quality standards that SE impose does NOT make your question any better. Asking quality questions will improve the site as a whole and improve your chances of getting a quality answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you ever want to do that?

Comment: @Barry, yes edited.

Comment: @Lohoris, to clear archived emails at regular intervals.

Comment: @Pacerier and, why would you want to do _that_? Why don't you just use the trash, which auto-cleans? Why delete them in the first place, since the inbox is so large?

Comment: @Lohoris, because the inbox is not big enough for me. Does the trash have a function to clear emails on a yearly basis? I don't want it to auto delete messages that I may still need.

Comment: @Pacerier no, it deletes them automatically after ~1 month, and that is not configurable. Are you sure you don't want to do that with a desktop client?

Comment: @Lohoris, the web has too many advantages

Comment: @Pacerier i.e., you want to have the advantages of both worlds without the disadvantages.

Comment: @Lohoris, that's wrong: why shouldn't a web email has the ability to filter out what has been archived and what has not been archived?

Comment: @Pacerier applications are suited to the needs of many users, while web apps usually have a minimal set of features. You have to accept this fact.

Comment: @Lohoris, are you living in Web 1.0?

Comment: @Pacerier you are detached from reality. Read again my two previous posts (not that I think you'll actually _read_ them).

Comment: @Lohoris, your detachment from reality results in you thinking that I'm detached from reality. Web apps usually have a minimal set of features? There are tons upon tons upon tons of web apps that have a full set of features. Do I get a minimal set of features from using Facebook via my browser? Web apps *sometimes* have a minimal set of features, not *usually*.

Comment: @Pacerier Facebook is born as a web app, it has a full set of features by _definition_. Gmail is just an interface to the email, you can chose to use it or use another client or write your own, hence it is pretty bound to have less features. If you can't tell the difference...

Comment: Comments are unable to be migrated at this point

Comment: @Lohoris. I'm aware that we can use another client to read our emails stored on Google's servers. Gmail is **not** "just an interface" to the emails. It is *the* interface to the emails. If you can't tell the difference...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In the Gmail search box, type

```
-label:inbox -label:sent -label:drafts -label:notes
```

and press enter. That should give you all your archived messages. Once there, select **All** and then click **Select all conversations that match this search** to ensure that all messages are selected. Click **Delete**.

They'd still go the the Trash though so you'd have to empty the Trash as a final step.

Comment: The dash is really a "minus" sign. So it means stuff that doesn't have this. It's a general google syntax: http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=136861

Comment: R.K.'s suggestion has a potentially disastrous side effect: If you have emails that have other labels (i.e. "Emails from Mom"), those emails will be selected (and trashed) as well. In addition, when you go to the trash to remove them, they will have all of their custom labels skipped. (I'm sorry, I tried to leave this as a comment but can't find or don't have that option)

Comment: I wouldn't call it a side effect. He did ask for a way to find *all archived emails*. Whether or not it has other labels is irrelevant. It is still archived. At least according to his question.

Comment: I'd say the answer is fine. If you added a label to a message and don't remove it from the inbox, then it won't be deleted. Otherwise, it's archived. Anyway, the answer gives an excellent idea on what to do if you want to keep those tags! Just add `-label:Mom` to the query! :)

Answer (score 10):

Our company's email is hosted by Google Apps, and I asked Google Enterprise Support the same question. They answered that the search syntax for archived messages is:

```
has:nouserlabels -in:Sent -in:Chat -in:Draft -in:Inbox
```

Here's the reference documentation for Gmail's search: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en

Comment: This does not show archived messages that has user labels....

Comment: OT: is `has:nouserlabels` new? I searched for such a thing ~1 year ago and it wasn't there! Or is it exclusive to Google Apps? _edit_: I tried, and it works on standard gmail too. Great!

Comment: The search suggested will not return messages with labels as @Pacerier mentioned.

Comment: @Rubén, Looks like "Google Enterprise Support" needs more staff training.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

- Try `-in:inbox` for archived messages.
- Try `in:anywhere -in:inbox` for messages archived, in Spam and in Trash.

## Explanation

In the Gmail Help lingo context, archive a message means removing it from Inbox, without asigning any label, but in a broadsense archived messages could means messages that moved from the Inbox to some place where it could be found later.

Type `in:anywhere` in the Gmail search box and hit enter. If the Conversation view is enabled this will return all the conversations in the current Gmail account mailbox including those messages indidually marked as Spam, deleted if the still are in Trash and the conversations in Inbox.

To find messages that are not in Inbox, nor in Spam nor in Trash type `-in:inbox`.

**Reference**
[Archive messages - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6576?hl=en)
[Advanced Search - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=7190)

Comment: You should use  -in:chats -in:spam -in:trash as well

Answer (score -1):

You can also type `in:archive` in the search box, that will show you all archived message then you can select which you want deleted.

Comment: Sure about that? It's not working for me. All I'm seeing is messages (and docs) with "archive" in the content.

Comment: -1 There isn't such search operator.

Comment: does work for me